# Feature activation powershell commands for SP 2010 to 2013 migration

Tags: migration, feature-activation

I heard there is a new Feature activation Powershell command which is used for migration of customization from SP 2010 to 2013.

Has any one used these command in real-time? Can we depend on this command for migration of big set of customization?

How much dependable is this command?

Comment: i never heard about this command, do you know about the command....It is hard to run a command and upgrade the solution.

Comment: i heard same thing... trying to collect info on this.